# p tag inside a tag css text center

Tags: html, css, less

I am designing a banner and the banner caption with some details in that the caption content a h2 tag and p tag.

In p tag there is a description within that p tag a tag link is also available. so want to to centered but not get it correct.

```
<p>printing and typesettinever since the 1500 <a href="#">Know More</a></p>
```

[image]

it is possible with

```
position: absolute;
left: 47%;
bottom: 33%;
```

[image: want the design like this]
css will fix it. i need another way to do.
i am new to css so try out new idea and possiblity.

Comment: Why not put a `<br>` tag before the `<a>`?

Comment: that is a possiblitiy, but i need a better solution. like it is design as two different tag

Comment: Or set display block on the a tag. Or use flexbox with flow column on the p tag.

Comment: @ArunSolomon "a better solution" - this is going to be subjective. There are so many options for this very simple question.

Comment: @disinfor That's not a good solution because it confuses structure for presentation. HTML is about structure, and adding a `br` only deals with presentation. If the OP wants to learn HTML, they need to learn how it works and not only how to get one particular page to look the way they want.

Comment: ` that is a possiblitiy, but i need a better solution. like it is design as two different tag ` so you know you want 2 different tags. Then why don't you use 2 different tags for the 2 elements ? .....

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the "Know more" text into a separate `p` element.

```html
<p>printing and typesettinever since the 1500</p>
<p><a href="#">Know More</a></p>
```

This is because `a` is a `display: inline` element by default, which means it does what you see here - it is displayed inline with other text.

The `p` element, by contrast, has `display: block` by default, which means it's treated as a distinct block of text by the browser.

The differences are very significant, in terms of how the two types of element are treated by the browser, and even which CSS attributes they're allowed to have.

The answer is NOT to make your `a` have the `display: block` property but just to split the existing `p` block into two, with the button in its own paragraph. You need to think about your layout in terms of how the various parts will display as blocks or as continuous sections of text, and then tag the content semantically using HTML. Then, your CSS will have the right context to get the page rendering correctly.

(There are lots of choices for exactly how you tag the elements - you could use `div`s instead of `p`s, for example. The 'correct' choice depends on the semantic structure of your page and how you want it structured. Here, I've just stuck with the tagging you had in place already.)

Comment: why not simply add a `<br />` before the `<a ...` ?

Comment: Because that doesn't really solve the problem. The "Know more" button isn't part of the same text flow as the previous text: it's a separate thing and needs treating separately. Adding a line break would only affect how the text displayed, not how it was interpreted. For example, different browsers might put different amounts of space between text and button. Even more significantly, a user accessing the page via screen reader would find it much easier to understand if marked up properly.

Comment: @MihaiT exactly. This will certainly work, but almost unnecessary since an `a` tag is already an inline-element within a `p` tag. Put a line break in there.

Comment: No - the fact that the `a` element is `inline` is exactly the OP's problem! Adding a line break only deals with presentation, not structure. Sure, it might make this particular page "look right" in one particular browser, but it doesn't help the OP understand how HTML works.

Comment: @JohnP - a screen reader would have no problem at all reading the text by putting in a line break before an anchor tag. Also, it doesn't need to be treated as something separately - it's text within the context of the paragraph. Creating a new paragraph for a link - I would argue - is creating a new context when there doesn't need to be one.

Comment: It's not in the context of the para, though. It *follows* the context of the paragraph. You may have a different opinion but I think helping the OP understand how the HTML and CSS are actually working is more useful than a quick hack to get this one page "looking right". Imagine, for a minute, that the OP next wants to change the spacing between the button and the text. Using a `br` gives them few options. Making the button a separate text block means they can use the usual `padding` and `margin` properties.

Comment: I would argue that a `<br>` is not a quick hack, since it's still semantically correct.  I don't think your answer is wrong, nor your reasoning. OP can technically make the `<a>` tag an `inline-block` element as well and all the options you mention are achievable. I even upvoted the answer.